# MVC 5 application on IIS 8 in Windows Server 2012 (virtual machine) is very slow (not only on initial load)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

The goal is to launch an **MVC 5** web app on an **IIS 8** within a **Windows Server 2012** (Standard edition for evaluation from Microsoft) in a **virtual machine** (VMware Workstation 12 Player, free version) in order to test the whole system for the release.

I managed to run the application, but the problem is, that it´s extremely slow. E.g. the index.html is a **static HTML** page and needs **more than 60 seconds** to load. But why? In Visual Studio and IIS Express still everything works perfectly.

*Futher information:*

1. On publishing, I **precompiled** the app. You can see the directory structure in the image below. I put these files into `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test"`.

[image]

2. The target framework is **.NET 4.6**. Therefore I´ve installed the [.NET 4.6 package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48137). The *DefaultAppPool* says v4.0, but apparently uses the correct 4.6 version.
3. For testing I´ve **added another application** to the same application pool - i.e. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\test2"` - where I put a hello-world index.html. It loads fast. Therefore I expect a **problem with MVC5**.
4. The Windows Server 2012 is running in a virtual machine. I gave the VM 4GB RAM and 6 CPU Cores (hyperthreaded), but it didn´t help. The task manager shows a **5% CPU** and **25% RAM consumption**. Therefore I assume that the **problem lies in the IIS**.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Something tells me that you are in the wrong Stack. But anyways you should check your caching configuration.

Comment: Both _cache_ and _kernel cache_ are enabled. Do you want me to add a rule (and which)?

Comment: what about static caching?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have finally found the problem: I use the Sql Server **LocalDb**, which is a local .mdf-file in the filesystem. The **Application Pool´s Identity** was set to *ApplicationPoolIdentity* and I had to change it to *LocalSystem*. Now the application pool can access the database and the IIS runs as it should.

What surprised me is, that even though the IIS didn´t *need* the database to load the index.html, it apparently tried to establish a connection right away. After unsuccessful 60s it said, *"Well I couldn´t connect, so I will try it without the database."* and continued loading. In case the database was not needed, it worked. I guess that happens due to the DB-Connection-Pooling.

Comment: well thats not IIS fault. its the code thats handling it propperly. try catch the query and return the error message that would have told you that right away.

Comment: The point is, that even when I accessed a page that didn´t need a DB connection (= a static HTML page), the page loaded slowly. Therefore it was hard to detect the error, because I thought it wouldn´t depend on the DB connection. Which brings me back to the DBCP-theorie. Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: If your code don't use the DB on a page then the db connection issues should not arise. Loading a purely static html file should have the same speed as loading a image (no connection needed for both, just a file download. The site should load nicely even if the web.config data connection is "unreachable".)

Comment: So if your problem is like you say, (that there is no code accessing the db but still the db issue arise, then this is a very interesting error, check by loading a css, js or just a image file or anything else that's static, if you really don't use the db on the static html page then they will load with the same issues, and we can with certainty say its a IIS issue. If not then the static page is not really static something is using the db (maybe in the viewpage, which loads around your "static" content page)

Comment: I looked for the reason in the code again, and recognised that all the Controllers all have an object of the Entity Framework Db context allocated - indirectly, over Dependency Injection. When the DI-Container creates the dependency tree it creates the Entity Framework context, which tries to access the DB-file. I guess the issue lies in Entity Framework or maybe in the DI-implementation (Ninject) then...