# MVC so slow on server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have made a website. Locally it works fine, no problems at all. But when I publish it to the server (VPS) it runs terribly slow. It takes almost 37 seconds for the homepage to load. While locally it takes like 400 ms.

I have no idea what to do because I tried a lot:

- Removing EF 6 and replaced it with dapper
- Using display templates instead of for each-loops and partials
- Removing all ViewEngines and adding only Razor.
- Checking duplicate queries (found one, fixed it)
- Checked unnecessary queries and used joins
- Checked if some functions are called to many times (loops)
- Tried to PreCompile during publishing

It became faster local. From 900 ms to 350 ms.

But on the server nothing seems to help. So I turned to the server.

For web application:

- Checked if debug was set on true on the server (was always false)
- Changed the connection string from (local) to 127.0.0.1,1234 (I use a port due to hackers. Port is not the real one in this example).
- Published as debug, not release

Server settings:

- Tried for force 32bit for the AppPool
- Put the web application in an own AppPool
- Disabled the ipv6
- Shutdown other AppPools
- Turned off the Windows FireWall (don't worry, turned it up again)
- Restarted the server again.

But then I noticed was that IIS Worker Process was using almost 1.7 GB memory, % of the memory and I was like "... What? Why?". Later I saw it was using 2.7 GB.

I installed Glimpse on the web application. But I cannot find out what the problem could be.

Some information of the techniques I use in the project:

- 3 layer: Business, Data, Web
- DI with Unity
- Bootstrap for design, jQuery
- EntityFramework 6 in the first version, Dapper in second
- MVC 5
- AspNet Identity for user management

VPS information:

- 4 GB
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v2 @ 2.80Ghz
- 64-bit OS
- Windows Server 2012

I can't think of any other information to give. So, if I missed something, just ask. If you want to check if out: Website is http://www.zatyscorner.com. I try to optimize the start page first so see what is happening.

Hopefully, someone can help me out.

Comment: which web hosting service you're using?

Comment: Strato (Germany). Speedtest showed 150 Mbit up, 100 Mbit down

Comment: Just now did a trace route, the result is a bit weird: https://snag.gy/J5cRNE.jpg, can you try this command: tracert www.zatyscorner.com and see which server response slowly..?

Comment: Can you test the page out in the web server??

Comment: Have you tried deploying an empty web application and if its slow as well?

Comment: @User2012384 url is registered at an other company and I have set the DNS to the Strato VPS. The timeouts are strange. The IP of the VPS starts with 85.214, so that means we are close, right?

I try to login on the server, but also the server is so slow. I think the internal memory is totally being used by IIS.

Comment: @User2012384 I tried to open the webpage locally on the server. Takes around 30 seconds. I also go an error timeout on query (had to translate it), has something to do with sql?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr If you check this URL: http://www.zatyscorner.com/Help/Index you will notice it will load very fast

Comment: I've checked it, it took 9 seconds for main page and milliseconds for the help index. Almost 8 seconds it took to respond on the main page. So there is really something on your Main Page or your controller that takes it too long to respond. Maybe you need to examine your database where you deployed your application, in my experience, it was already indexed on dev db but on the deployed server, index was not reflected.

Comment: Then I think you can narrow down to the performance and resource of that computer: is the CPU usage high? how much RAM does the computer have?? try run a single query in DB server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so back at programming-school I was taught that you have to do a few things when there are performance issues: Check the server, check the code and.... Check the queries...

Well, in this case, the queries to SQL were the bad guys. I had one query that took 7700 records (give or take), took 10 from those and showed it... Yeah, that will cause a timeout and enormous amount of memory... Especially when 3 people are doing it at the same time.

Problem fixed! I am rebuilding most queries now with Dapper and I make sure the good amount of records are returned.

Feeling like a noob :(

Comment: Make sure you've got indexes set up correctly on the database, it can make the world of difference!  I'd also think EF would handle getting back 10 records fine, simply using IQueryable to narrow your query down to 10 results should be pretty quick.

Comment: @Tom Indexes are set. I made sure of that. I did that with EF, but somehow it didn't work. It always got the 7700 records from the DB and then took 10 instead of getting 10 from the 7700.

Comment: It sounds like it wasn't using `IQueryable` all the way through.  Were you using Linq's `Skip` and `Take`?  It's possible you were using the `IEnumerable` implementations instead.  (I can't seem to @ your username!)

Answer (score 0):

I think changing the Application Pool's Identity to LocalSystem can help, check out this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379842/mvc-5-application-on-iis-8-in-windows-server-2012-virtual-machine-is-very-slow).

I will also suggest you to enable output caching on your IIS if you haven't done yet. Enable it for all image files i.e. .png,.jpg, etc., .css files, html and cshtml files and js files too.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/managing-performance-settings/configure-iis-7-output-caching) is how you can do it

Comment: I don't think caching image helps a lot loading a page takes minutes isn't normal

Comment: Not at this moment, but maybe in a later stage. I need to take a look at caching at some point.